# MD5 Bruteforce, Issue translating from Python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, recursion, hash, md5

I prototyped this function yesterday in python to bruteforce an md5 hash and it works beautifully. 
In this case it will print `Match: aa` and `4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912`. Since this is the hash for the string "aa".

```python
import hashlib

def crack(chars, st, hsh):
    if chars == 0:
        if hashlib.md5(st).hexdigest() == hsh:
            print "Match: " + st
            print hashlib.md5(st).hexdigest()
    else:
        for i in range(32,127):
            new = st + str(unichr(i))
            crack(chars - 1, new, hsh)

crack(2, "", "4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912")
```

Now I'm trying to implement it in javascript. I am already using an md5 library and it is working fine. Here's the code I wrote, the recursion is not working as expected. I will show the code and the console output to illustrate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <script src="js/md5.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
    function crack(chars, st, hsh){
        console.log(chars);
        console.log(st);
        if (chars == 0){
            if (md5(st) == hsh){
                console.log(st);
            }
        }
        else {
            for  (i = 32; i <= 126; i++){
                newst = st + String.fromCharCode(i);
                crack(chars - 1, newst, hsh);
            }
        }
    }

    crack(2, "", "4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the console output:

```
2
(space ascii 32)
1
(space ascii 32) 
0
(space ascii 32)   
0
!
0
"
0
#
0
$
0
%
0
&
0
etc.
0
~ (ascii 126)
```

What kind of sorcery is required to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop iterator `i` is a global variable. Make it local with `var` or `let`:

```js
 function crack(chars, st, hsh) {
   if (chars == 0) {
     if (md5(st) == hsh) {
       console.log(st);
     }
   } else {
     for (var i = 32; i <= 126; i++) {   // <--- Declare i with var or let
       var newst = st + String.fromCharCode(i);
       crack(chars - 1, newst, hsh);
     }
   }
 }

 crack(2, "", "4124bc0a9335c27f086f24ba207a4912");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-md5/2.3.0/js/md5.min.js"></script>
```

Incrementing a global iterator variable `i` in a recursive function call increases its value for the caller, too.